# What does this code mean (s, e)?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-oob

How does this code work?

```
      app.InstallStateChanged += (s, e) => UpdateUI();
      NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged +=
            (s, e) => UpdateNetworkIndicator();
```

Can someone please unscramble this?

The code comes from an example used in a silverlight 4 OOB systems http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833066(v=VS.95).aspx

UpdateNetworkIndicator does not return anything.
UpdateUI does not return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the UpdateUI() and UpdateNetworkIndicator() methods are custom event handler methods.

The += operator is attaching these event handlers to the events fired by the app and NetworkChange respectively.

The => denotes a lambda expression. The (s,e) are input parameters (in this case, the standard **sender, event args**) and the right of => is the statement or expression.

In this case, you could rewrite this as:

```
app.InstallStateChanged += UpdateUI;
NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += UpdateNetworkIndicator;
```

and it should work just as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this! I've ticked this one because it convert the confusing to something I understand but I do appreciate the other comments that have improved my understanding.

Answer (score 9):

That's a lambda expression.

> "All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as
>   "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or
>   statement block. The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x
>   times x."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 9):

This is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that contains multiple parameters.  In this case (as you are using the function to replace an event handler) they are equivalent to the `object` and `EventArgs` parameters.

Your code is equivalent to the below

```
app.InstallStateChanged += OnInstallStateChanged;
NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += OnNetworkAddressChanged;

/* ... */

private void OnInstallStateChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateUI();
}

private void OnNetworkAddressChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateNetworkIndicator();
}
```

Comment: +1 This answer gets my vote.  Sets the appropriate pattern for a __good__ stackoverflow answer IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example

```
Button1.Click += (s, e) => log(e);
```

is the short hand (using lambda expression) for

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

and

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

InstallStateChanged and NetworkAddressChanged are Events, what you´re seeing is the lambda syntax to define eventhandler to call UpdateUI or UpdateNetworkIndicator if the respective events are fired.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is called [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). From MSDN,

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain
>   expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or
>   expression tree types.

And the  `(s, e)` declare input parameters of created delegate or expression tree. When there's single input parameter, parentheses are not needed and you can write just `s => ...`. When there's more than one parameter, parentheses are required - `(s, e) =>`.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the s and e refer to objects whose properties the function is targeting. The code is expressing: you have two types of objects you can access in this function. When this function is invoked, from the s object get this or that property and use its value in the following way.

So in a hypothetical context

S is a string
E is an int

(s, e) =>

Means that further references in the function are referring to those respective object types by the names s and e.

(s , e) => s.Length + e

Means: get the value of the instance of a string to which s refers and add to it the value of the instance of an int to which e refers.